# How can I debug With WebKit?compile WebKit source code Failed

Tags: ios, xcode, build, webkit

I want debug my webView with Webkit, but compile WebKit Failed. When I use command : Tools/Scripts/build-webkit --debug --ios-simulator, ** BUILD FAILED **.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2TOJ.png)

When I build with Xcode, also failed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax6DC.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjj4u.png)

I saw All Source in some people's documents, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhKqx.png)
But I did not find in my Xcode.

How can I build success with Xcode? My Mac is M2, Xcode version is 15. Is there a detailed document to learn? Thanks

I need a source code that could debug in Xcode, or a detailed document to learn how to build it.